# Get the missing objects from a ModelNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Considering the following scenario:

```
User::findOrFail([1,2,5,6]);
```

Let's say that users with `id = 5` and `id = 6` do not exist in database. Therefore, **ModelNotFoundException exception** will be thrown.

Is there a way to know which are the missing users?
I would like to know that the only users that do not exist in database are 5 and 6.

Thanks!

Comment: Not without testing each individually, unless it's thrown in the exception message. In your catch block just $e->getMessage();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of determining which were not found using `findOrFail`, because the method just compares the number of items returned from the database, with the number of IDs you passed as a parameter (it does not care which are the IDs that where not found). When it throws the exception, it just passes the model class name and nothing more:

```php
throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(get_class($this->model));
```

You'll need to implement the logic yourself if you want that. Here's an approach:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 5, 6];

// Find the users
$users = User::find($ids)->get();

// Find the IDs that did not match
$notFoundIds = array_diff($ids, $users->modelKeys('id'));

if ( ! empty($notFoundIds))
{
    // throw your exception here
    // the missing IDs are in $notFoundIds
}
```